# Configure Nexus via command line (non gui)

Tags: bash, ldap, repository, sonatype, nexus3

I have dockerized Nexus3, I have this requirement to automate the configuration of LDAP, nexus-data via command line (bash script). However, I've been searching this in the documentation if they have cli functions which can do these requirements, but I couldn't find it.
Is there any way I can do these via command line.

I am just integrating the LDAP server via Nexus UI (Admin account)

Please advise.